# Northwind action query error msg "multi-valued fields are not allowed in select into statements"

Tags: ms-access, northwind

I downloaded a Northwind template and am unable to run any type of action queries on the app's tables.  I get error messages such as:

1. "multi-valued fields are not allowed in select into statements".
2. "Select* cannot be used in an insert query when the source or destination table contains mutli-value field"

Is there a way to run action queries to this app's tables without having to use VBA?

Thank You very much in advance, Nathaniel

```
SELECT Orders.*, * INTO d
FROM Orders;


INSERT INTO [Copy Of Products] ( [Product Code], [Product Name], [List Price], [Supplier IDs], Discontinued, Category, Attachments )
SELECT Sheet4.ID, Sheet4.DESCRIPTION, "1" AS Expr1, "11" AS Expr2, "False" AS Expr3, Sheet4.COMMODITY_CODE, "0" AS Expr4, *
FROM Sheet4;
```

Comment: Get rid of the multi-value fields (look-up fields) from the tables. They are only of use if you are working with Sharepoint. Otherwise it is best to just have a look-up table that is referenced in forms etc. If you really must : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/using-multivalued-fields-in-queries-HA010149297.aspx#BM8

Comment: I opened the products table in design view and I changed all of the display controls that were a combobox to a textbox, but I am still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three problems with the Products table from a standard design point of view.

1. It is associated with the suppliers table (both in the property sheet and the supplier ids field).
2. Categories is a multi-value field.
3. Attachments is attachment type.

You should be able to run an update query as long as none of these fields are included. In your example, you have [Supplier IDs]. In standard design, you would have a junction table for products / suppliers.

Comment: I modified my query to not include the fields that you mentioned, but I am still getting the error message.  INSERT INTO [Copy Of Products] ( [Product Code], [Product Name], [List Price] )
SELECT Sheet4.ID, Sheet4.DESCRIPTION, Sheet4.UNIT_PRICE, *
FROM Sheet4;

Comment: You have use * in your query and the error is * cannot be used with tables that contain multi-value fields, here `UNIT_PRICE, * FROM`